# How do you update list from changing values in row of selected index of datagridview?

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I have a list within a class called vehicle. This contains its own list that is called activity that contains instances of different activities which are also classes. When I add activities to a particular vehicles activity list, it adds a new instance of that activity and refreshes the datagridview to display the list of activities. What I would like to do is click a row in the datagridview and populate some textboxes, then have a button that updates the activity object in the list.

This is how I retrieve the list:

```
private Vehicle _activeVehicle; //Where _activeVehicle is set prior as a specific instance of a vehicle

var list = _activeVehicle.ActivityList;
```

Here is the class for my activity that is added to the activity list:

```
public class Relocate : Activity
{
    private string _distance;
    private string _type;
    private string _name;
    private string _cost;
    private DateTime _date;
    private string _start;

    public string Type { get => _type; set => _type = value; }

    public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value; }

    public string Cost { get => _cost; set => _cost = value; }

    public DateTime Date { get => _date; set => _date = value; }

    public string Distance { get => _distance; set => _distance = value; }

    public string Start { get => _start; set => _start = value; }
}
```

When an item in the datagridview is clicked, I have a row click method that adds the values of each cell in that row too some textboxes. Currently I am directly getting the values as shown below,  but ideally I would like to select the actual object from the list to populate the textboxes, but Im not sure how to do that based off of a datagridview cell click. Here is how I do it:

```
DataGridView table = relocationDataGridView;
                    table.ClearSelection();
                    DataGridView.HitTestInfo index = table.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                    table.Rows[index.RowIndex].Selected = true;
                    IndexRelocate = index.RowIndex;
                    DataGridViewRow dataGrid = table.Rows[index.RowIndex];

                    switch (index.RowIndex)
                    {
                        case -1:
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("This is not a record", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                return;
                            }
                        default:
                            {
                                relocationCostTextBox.Text = dataGrid.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                                relocationStartTextBox.Text = dataGrid.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                                relocationTypeTextBox.Text = dataGrid.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                                relocationEndTextBox.Text = dataGrid.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                                relocationDistanceTextBox.Text = dataGrid.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                                relocationDateTimePicker.Value = (DateTime)dataGrid.Cells[5].Value;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
```

Relocation is the activity in the datagridview, where the class has the attributes of `Cost, Start, Type, End, Distance, Date`

What I would like to do is update the specific object in the list, where the list belongs to `_activeVehicle` from clicking the datagridview, entering new details in the textboxes, and clicking an update button, but Im not sure where to start with writing the code for this. The code below populates the textboxes with the current details of the selected row, but would be better if it used that row for reference and pulled the data from the list belonging to `_activeVehicle`. How might I achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like you may need to research `DataBindings` for a text box. Something like… `relocationCostTextBox.DataBindings.Add(“Text”, list, “Cost”);` … [Control.DataBindings Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.databindings?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Ill look into that thanks